# TightVNC server loop reconnecting

Tags: vnc, tightvnc

I have a vm running windows 10 on which I have installed Tightvnc 2.8.81 to which I connect with novnc. What happens is that often (about every 5-10 minutes even getting to do it a couple of times a minute) the connection goes in a loop, alternately appearing the words "connecting" and "reconnecting" very quickly and after a few seconds it fixes itself only to do it again in a few minutes.
I set the TightVNC log level to 3 and in the file I see this:

```
[ 3484/ 6044] 2023-10-16 14:49:04 + Echo extension request handler deleted
[ 3484/  816] 2023-10-16 14:49:04 + Echo extension request handler deleted
[ 3484/ 3804] 2023-10-16 14:49:04 + Connection from 10.127.0.113 has been closed for client #66
[ 3484/ 3804] 2023-10-16 14:49:04 + Connection from 10.127.0.113 has been closed for client #223
```

There are hundreds of such lines, it seems to be creating too many connections and closing them all at once.